# my if condition is not working on processing language

Tags: if-statement, processing

I'm working on Processing language for my assignment. It's an animation. The animation object(a ball) needs to go from top to bottom. I have declared variable as `float x,y`. Whenever I put if condition to increase size of it by 1 but it's not moving a single inch.

```
float x;
float y;

size(600, 400)

x = 0.4*width/8;
y = 0.4*height/8;


ellipse( width/2, x, 0.8*width/8, 0.8*width/8);
ellipse( y, height/2, 0.8*height/8, 0.8*height/8);



if(x < height){
    x = x+1;
}

if(y < width){
   y=y+1;
}
```

I am expecting the output as- the ball located on top moves towards down and stops at the bottom and the left ball moves to right and stops at the rightmost point.

Answer (score 4):

You're using Processing in "static mode" which means your code runs **once** and then is done. Nothing happens after you reach the end of your code.

To take advantage of Processing's 60 FPS rendering loop, you need to specify `setup()` and `draw()` functions. Something like this:

```java
float circleY;

void setup(){
  size(200, 200);
  circleY = height/2;
}

void draw(){
  background(200);
  ellipse(100, circleY, 20, 20);

  circleY = circleY + 1;
}
```

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/animation) is a tutorial on animation in Processing.